# How do you prove $X_n=sin(n\omega)$ diverges for a uniform random variable $\omega \in [0,1]$?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

How do you prove the random process $X_n=sin(n\omega)$ does not converge for any types of convergence for probability (surely, almost surely, probability, quadratic mean, distribution)?

Assume $n$ is a natural number and $\omega \in  [0,1]$ is a uniform random variable.

Here is my attempt: I know that if you let $\omega=0$, then then $X_n=0$ and converges.  However, if $\omega \in (0,1]$ then $X_n$ has frequencies that get bigger and bigger, and hence diverges. This makes sense to me at a high level, but how do you prove the sequence diverges for $\omega \in (0,1]$ ?